# How to find unicode characters by their descriptive names?

Tags: python, python-2.7, unicode, python-2.x

Trying to get a unicode character by the (unique) name in python 2.7.  The method I've found in the [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/unicodedata.html#module-unicodedata) is not working for me:

```
>>> import unicodedata
>>> print unicodedata.lookup('PILE OF POO')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
KeyError: "undefined character name 'PILE OF POO'"
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is, that [PILE OF POO](http://codepoints.net/U+1F4A9) was introduced with Unicode 6. However, the data of `unicodedata` is mostly older, 5.X versions or so. The docs say:

> The module uses the same names and symbols as defined by the UnicodeData File Format 5.2.0 (see http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr44/tr44-4.html).

This means, unfortunately, that you also are out of luck with almost all [Emoji and hieroglyphs](http://codepoints.net/search?age[]=6.0&age[]=6.1&age[]=6.2&age[]=6.3&age[]=7.0) (if you're into egyptology).

Comment: Python 2.7 uses Unicode 5.2, Python 3.4 uses 6.3 according to the documentation. Other 3.x versions probably use correspondingly older Unicode data.

Comment: Works in Python 3.4.0.

Comment: unicodedata.unidata_version gives the version of Unicode your Python is using.  It must be >= 6.0 to get the PILE OF POO.